# Extract data from a signal

Tags: elm, elm-signal

I have a signal like this: `signal1 = Signal.constant {a=4, b=3, l = []}`
How do I extract a data from the signal?
I have tried `Signal.map (\x -> x) signal1` but `Signal.map` returns another signal.

Answer (score 4):

If while programming in Elm you ever have questions like:

- *“how do I extract value from a signal?”*
- *“how do I change this variable to another value?”*
- *“where do I put `foldp` and what arguments should I pass into it?”*

you should read [*The Elm Architecture*](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/) tutorial and try to implement its code along the way. Seriously, any novice Elm programmer should diligently go through this tutorial from start to finish, as it will clear much of the confusion.

Nevertheless, I'll give a simplified summary — bear in mind I omit lots of details and complexities. If you've read the tutorial, you probably understand, how a typical Elm program is structured. There are 3 main parts in most Elm programs: model, update, and view.

Model contains initial values for all your program data, and their type definitions. Update takes an event and a model, and returns a modified model based on the event. View takes a model (at whatever stage the program currently is) and draws it on screen, in other words, returns an `Element`.

In a simple program, you can immediately render whatever your signals emit, without storing any intermediate state, just by applying [`Signal.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#map) to a rendering function and a signal. Below, function [`show`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Graphics-Element#show) plays the role of your primitive view. You don't use any models or updates, because you immediately render whenever the mouse signal emits new event.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
import Mouse
import Signal exposing (Signal, map)

main : Signal Element
main = map show Mouse.isDown
```

But if you want to [maintain state between the events](http://elm-lang.org/guide/reactivity), you have to use [`foldp`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#foldp), either directly or through some higher-level abstraction. By state I mean your model, modified by successive applications of your update function. At any point in time your model is in a certain state. Your `main` would usually look something like this:

```
main = map view (foldp update model signal)
```

`main` function always has the type `Signal Element` — there are exceptions, but behind the scenes they are converted to `Signal Element` anyway. Whatever you do with your data, code, and functions, at some point you have to combine it all into something of type `Signal Element`, which will be the body of your `main` function.

A model is usually a [record](http://elm-lang.org/docs/records) with many fields, any of which can be records too. An update usually has type `Event -> Model -> Model`, where `Model` is a type of your model and `Event` is whatever your final signal emits. A view usually has the type `Model -> Element`. (The type names don't have to be `Event` and `Model`, I use them as placeholders in this example).

*You can't extract values from a Signal*, this is deliberately impossible in Elm. Instead you *lift* a function into the `Signal` *context*, using `Signal.map`. All the manipulation with values emitted by signal is done within `Signal` context by functions that are lifted into it. Suppose you have a `signal` of type `Signal Event`. Then `foldp update model signal` will have type `Signal Model`, because `foldp` has the type:

```
foldp : (a -> state -> state) -> state -> Signal a -> Signal state
```

If your view function has the type `Model -> Element`, then `map view (foldp update model signal)` will have the type `Signal Element`.

`main` is mandated to have the type `Signal Element`, therefore `map view (foldp update model signal)` can be the body of `main`.

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
import Mouse
import Signal exposing (Signal, foldp, map)

type alias Model = Int
model : Model
model = 0

update : () -> Model -> Model
update event model = model + 1

view : Model -> Element
view model = show model

main : Signal Element
main = map view (foldp update model Mouse.clicks)
```

Above is a very simple program that accumulates mouse clicks. We have a dummy event, and our model is just an integer. How does `Signal.map` function work? It has the type:

```
map : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
```

It takes an ordinary function that converts a value into another value, and takes a signal of the first value, to produce a signal of the second value. Suppose you have lots of various signals, they emit values corresponding to mouse clicks, key presses, timed events, HTML input fields, all kinds of stuff. You manipulate these signals any way you like, but at some point you [`merge`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Signal#merge) them into one final signal, with type `Signal Something` (where Something corresponds to a complicated datatype, containing all input data you need for the program).

Because you must have a `main` function, at some point you will have to convert your final signal to `Signal Element`, so at some point you will have to map (lift) a function of type `Something -> Element` over `Signal Something` to get `Signal Element`. Why is it called *lifting*? Because of [partial application](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#applying-functions) these 2 type definitions of `Signal.map` are equivalent:

```
map : (a -> b) -> Signal a -> Signal b
map : (a -> b) -> (Signal a -> Signal b)
```

You *lift* an ordinary day-to-day function of type `a -> b` into the `Signal` *context*, so that it can work on signals of values instead of just values. Here is a more complicated example that counts both seconds and mouse clicks:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
import Mouse
import Signal exposing (Signal, foldp, map, merge)
import Time exposing (Time, fps, inSeconds)

type alias Model = { clicks : Int, time : Int }
model : Model
model = { clicks=0, time=0 }

type Event = Seconds Int | Mouse ()
update : Event -> Model -> Model
update event model = case event of
  Seconds time -> { model | time <- model.time + time }
  Mouse () -> { model | clicks <- model.clicks + 1 }

view : Model -> Element
view model = show model

timeSignal = Seconds << round << inSeconds <~ fps 1
mouseSignal = map Mouse Mouse.clicks

signal : Signal Event
signal = merge timeSignal mouseSignal

main : Signal Element
main = map view (foldp update model signal)
```

Now, I hope, you have a basic understanding how Elm programs are structured and how to handle events emitted by signals and modify your data from event to event. Now you can extend the above program by adding more signals, making your model more complex, and making your view draw fancier output.

Answer (score 1):

This is deliberately near impossible, because you should not need to.

Why? Well, it may help to look at one possible signature for main in an Elm application:

```
main : Signal Element
```

Here, we declare that the type of our program is a Signal of Element; this means that our program is an Element that changes over time. The Elm runtime will sort out the 'changing over time' bit for us, so long as we let it know what signals we care about (by referencing them), and how to connect them together (using map, foldp, and so on).

If you are attempting to access the inner value to display it as part of your application - the right way to go is to use that main signature, and let Elm do the Signal unwrapping.

If you just want to look at a value at runtime (in the console log, for example), take a look at:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Debug

Comment: But I am using StartApp module and I cannot use signals inside model, do I?

Comment: There shouldn't be any `Signal`s inside your model. Can you provide some code showing what you're trying to do?