# What is the expected behaviour of Random.initialSeed in elm (v0.15)

Tags: random, elm

Is initialSeed supposed to provide a different seed each time it is called?  The following code always provides the same value:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Random exposing(float, generate, initialSeed)

main = 
    show (generate (float 0 1 ) (initialSeed 31415))
```

If this code is behaving correctly, would you kindly give a pointer on the usage of random numbers and Random.generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialSeed` is a function which given an `Int` produces a `Seed` which can then be used in the `generate` function. Because Elm is purely function, giving `generate` the same `Generator` and `Seed` will always produce the same value. However, `generate` also returns the next `Seed` to be used in your next call to `generate`. This in allows you to reproduce the same sequence of randomly generated values.

Example usage:

```
import Random
import Graphics.Element as Element

-- Int Generator that computes random numbers in the range [0, 10]
intGenerator = Random.int 0 10

-- Change this to get different sequences.
seed = Random.initialSeed 42
--seed = Random.initialSeed 1234
--seed = Random.initialSeed 0

-- Generates a random x and returns the next seed to be used. Note:
-- This will always return the same x because it uses the same seed
-- this is a result of Elm being purely functional. However,
-- because this returns a new seed, you can use that to get the next
-- random value in the sequence
(x, seed') = (Random.generate intGenerator seed)

-- Generate the next element in the sequence
(y, seed'') = (Random.generate intGenerator seed')
(z, seed''') = (Random.generate intGenerator seed'')

main = Element.show [x, y, z]
```

on share-elm.com: http://share-elm.com/sprout/55c766b4e4b06aacf0e8be1b

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Random`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Random) is super-easy in Elm 0.15. *(I assume you understand how Elm naturally separates data and code into model, update, and view. If your understanding of Elm architecture is shaky, read [The Elm Architecture](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/) tutorial and [simple explanation of model-view-update pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31931698/596361)).*

The most important function is [`generate`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Random#generate), it returns a pair: a random value and a new seed. This new seed you can pass into `generate` again, to yield a new random value and yet another seed. However passing the same seed yields the same “random” value. The below code renders **59**:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Random exposing (generate, int, initialSeed)

main =
  let (number, seed) = generate (int 0 99) (initialSeed 1234)
  in show number
```

You need to save this new seed between any 2 random value generations somehow. And each time you use `generate`, pass the new seed instead of the old one. How do you do that?

You store the seed inside your model and make sure that during update stage you overwrite the old seed with the new seed:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
import Mouse exposing (clicks)
import Random exposing (Seed, initialSeed, generate, int)
import Signal exposing (Signal, foldp)

seed0 = initialSeed 1234

type alias Model = { num : Int, seed : Seed }

defaultModel : Model
defaultModel = { num = 0, seed = seed0 } -- initial seed in the model

update : () -> Model -> Model
update _ model =
  let (newNum, newSeed) = generate (int 0 99) model.seed -- new value and new seed
  in { model | num <- newNum, seed <- newSeed } -- update model with new seed

view : Model -> Element
view model = show model.num

-- new random value each time mouse clicked
main = Signal.map view <| foldp update defaultModel clicks
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I can' t really see the point of the whole generate mechanism.  You need a signal to generate the initial seed (otherwise your program will have the same sequence each time it runs) and i think Elm used to directly use the signal to provide the randomness.  As the signal always has to be hanging around, what does the added complexity of the generator gain you.